# AFNetworking - Serialize Connection

Tags: ios, grails, afnetworking

I use AFNetworking as my connection lib to my app. Due to the back-end restrictions, I cannot send two request simultaneously when the app starts because the server will identify a CookieTheftException (Grails). After a first successful connection, I can do as many simultaneous requests as I want but the first need to be serial. 
How can I achieve that?

I thought using a Semaphore but i can't block the main thread.

#### Edit 1

I tried to override but it didn't work. I think the operation queue doesn't wait one request to finish (including it's callback) to start the other.

```
- (void)enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation
{
    [self.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    [super enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

#### Edit 2

I realized that the maxConcurrentOperation worked and in fact 1 operation is executed at a time. The problem is that the request enqueued is already created without the cookies the server needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know anything about Grails or the specific architecture of your system, but perhaps this could be solved by simply turning off cookies on that request, with `NSMutableURLRequest -setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:`.

Other than that, the best way to ensure that only one request operation is ever running for that initial call would be to ignore queues altogether, and simply have an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` property on your `AFHTTPClient` subclass. You could even get fancy with KVO to ensure that the operation queue is suspended until that initial request is finished.

Comment: Hi mattt, thnxs for your help. Using KVO to check when the first request is done and "dispatch_resume" the queue worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to read about [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

You can create a queue and put some block to be executed in this queue.

This way:

- It won't block main thread
- Since all your networking blocks will be executed in one queue, there is no way that two blocks will be executed simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the maximum concurrent operations of the queue to 1.  That way only one request will be made at a time.

```
[self.httpClient.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

But since you only need to wait for the first request, why not just call that request on its own, then initialize the other requests only when the first one completed?

Comment: I dont want to lock the user when the first request is ocurring. By the way, he can use the app offline and at any moment the internet can turn on and the first request needs to be serialized.

Comment: I believe you can still call your request in the background (asynchronously) even if the max concurrent op count is 1.  Worth a shot.